# Politoed Breeding

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

[Politoed](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Politoed) is an evolution from Poliwhirl when traded holding a King's Rock. It is one of Poliwag's final forms, the other being Poliwrath.

In Bulbapedia says some moves can only be learned by [breeding](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Politoed#By_breeding), and this is my question.

When you Breed an evolved Pokemon, you will always get the first evolution. In cases like this (evolution by trade), does it work the same way? If I put 2 Politoeds in day care (male and female), will they produce an egg of Poliwag or Politoed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pokemon **always** breed into the lowest tier of the evolution.*

This means that mated pairs of both Politoed and Poliwrath will produce Poliwag eggs.

All four pokemon have the same moves available "via breeding", which makes sense, given the above.

`*`  unless the requirements for a "baby" pokemon form is not met, in which case they will be the next-evolved form.

Comment: Could you explain " unless the requirements for a "baby" pokemon form is not met, in which case they will be the next-evolved form. " ?

Comment: @MichelAyres Some pokemon (Politoed is not one of them) have a "baby" or "prevolution" form that cannot be found in the wild. These can usually only be bred if their parents are holding special items - see Wynaut, Cleffa, Igglybuff, Magby, Pichu, et al. Otherwise, they will breed the middle evolution - wobbuffet, clefairy, jigglypuff, magmar, or pikachu.

Comment: And specifically, those baby forms only have that limitation because they were added in later generations than the grown up versions.  It's their way of logicking away why you couldn't breed them in the first place.